# How to Restore Database in Server's sql server Database?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have 2 database  test1 and test2.
I got the backup from test1. And now i want to restore this backup into test2.

My test2 database in shared server. When I am doing restore it's get failed. and populate this error message.

```
Msg 3110, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
User does not have permission to RESTORE database 'databasename'.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

i set the permission to the user of db_backupoperator. but it's still not restoring database.
Please let me know that what i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: db_backupoperator lets you backup a database. It has nothing to say about restores.

Comment: I know only these things about restore and backup so i tried that.

Answer (score 7):

You will need the `db_creator` permission in order to successfully restore a database.

From [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx):

> Permissions If the database being restored does not exist, the user
>   must have CREATE DATABASE permissions to be able to execute RESTORE.
>   If the database exists, RESTORE permissions default to members of the
>   sysadmin and dbcreator fixed server roles and the owner (dbo) of the
>   database (for the FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT option, the database always
>   exists). RESTORE permissions are given to roles in which membership
>   information is always readily available to the server. Because fixed
>   database role membership can be checked only when the database is
>   accessible and undamaged, which is not always the case when RESTORE is
>   executed, members of the db_owner fixed database role do not have
>   RESTORE permissions.

Answer (score 0):

**db_backupoperator** can BACKUP databases only. They cannot RESTORE.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189041(v=SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need dbcreator or sysadmin role to restore database. 
For more information on database roles you can check - [MSSQL Server roles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx)