# How to backup and restore in c#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup, restore

I developed a windows C# .net application and I use Sqlserver database.
I created database in a special user named *admin*.
And now I want to backup and restore database.

So I am successful in backing up but I get error while restoring

```
 private void pictureBox6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SaveFileDialog f = new SaveFileDialog();
                f.InitialDirectory = "D:\\";
                f.Title = "HoghooghDastmozdBackup";
                f.FileName = "HoghooghDastmozdBackup";
                f.FilterIndex = 1;
                f.OverwritePrompt = true;
                f.Filter = @"SQL Backup files (*.BAK) |*.BAK|All files(*.*) |*.*";
                if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=HoghooghDastmozd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=admin;password=123456admin");
                    //   SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE HoghooghDastmozd TO  DISK =@n", sqlconn);
                    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE [HoghooghDastmozd] TO  DISK = @n WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'HoghooghDastmozd-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10",sqlconn);
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", f.FileName);
                    sqlconn.Open();
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlconn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("عملیات پشتیبانی موفق بود");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }


 private void pictureBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
                f.InitialDirectory = "D:\\";
                f.Title = "HoghooghDastmozdBackup";
                f.FileName = "HoghooghDastmozdBackup";
                f.Filter = @"SQL Backup files (*.BAK) |*.BAK|All files(*.*) |*.*";
                if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection("");
                    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE HoghooghDastmozd  SET SINGLE_USER with ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE " + "use master   " + "RESTORE DATABASE [HoghooghDastmozd] FROM  DISK = @n WITH REPLACE ", sqlconn);
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", f.FileName);
                    sqlconn.Open();
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlconn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("عملیات بازیابی موفق بود");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Error Image: 
[image: Error image]

I have granted these permission but not work:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin', mobtaker;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', mobtaker;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', mobtaker;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', mobtaker;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'dbcreator', mobtaker;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'sysadmin', mobtaker;
```

Comment: Who is mobtaker?  I thought your user was called admin?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to make sure you have the correct permissions is to make a new blank database (you will be an owner automatically) and then restore your BAK over it.  This [page](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/121/restore-sql-server-database-and-overwrite-existing-database/) tells you how...

Comment: Yes You Are Right.when I create a login named 'admin' and pass='123456admin'.and I create my db in this login so I can not restore database.I get error.

Comment: Dear Ash8087 Please Answer

Comment: Is your admin user a member of dbcreator or sysadmin?  If not, he won't be able to create a new database.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059688/how-to-restore-database-in-servers-sql-server-database